# How can I get every character from an array and place it into another one?

Tags: c

I am working on a program in **c**, and I have two variables: `file[]` and `tok[]`. The idea is to iterate through `file[]` character by character and place the characters in `tok[]`. I can print the characters from `file[]` directly, but I can't place them into `tok[]`. How would I grab `file[]`, **character by character** and place it **character by character** into `tok[]`?

My `main()` method (always returns 0 without any errors):

```
int main()
{
    char file[] = "PRINT \"Hello, world!\"";
    int filelen = strlen(file);
    int i = 0;
    char tok[] = "";

    for (i = 0; i < filelen; i++) {
        printf("%c \n", file[i]); // Print every char from variable file
        tok[strlen(tok)+1] = file[i]; // Add the character to variable tok

        printf("%s \n", tok); // Print tok

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a few errors:

```
    char tok[] = "";
```

This allocates a fixed-length array of *one*! The memory is not automatically expanded when you add characters. As you want to copy `filelen` characters, you should do:

```
    char tok[filelen+1];   // note the "+1" for the terminating null character
```

In your loop, you repeatedly call `strlen`. Personally I find that a waste of CPU cycles and would prefer to use another index variable, for example:

```
    int toklen= 0;   // initially empty
    ...
        tok[toklen++] = file[i]; // Add the character to variable tok
```

In your version you have added the character one position too far (indices in C go from `0..n-1`).

After the loop you must still terminate the string with a null character:

```
    tok[toklen] = '\0';
```